# Issue sending html email with images in php

Tags: php, html, email, ob-start

I have two HTML templates. And I buffer them into php email using `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. However, one can be sent without any problem while another has no images in the email body. Can anyone find what the problems are? Here are the two templates:

- the good one: http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/good.txt
- the bad one: http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/bad.txt

I have tried to use absolute path for images, and tried to use img tag instead of div with background image, but they don't work.

Comment: Actually, I found the problem. The template needs to be one single file, with all styles. Because the email can not go back to remote server to achieve css and other once it's send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about inline image? you can convert the img into data first. http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

Comment: not only image, actually all external style are not working. you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can try uploading images to cloud and use them from there....I am not sure...but may be this helps..!!! Also, remember putting ob_flush() in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are using CSS in bad.txt file which path you have mentioned is given below.

link href="quote.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

so please mentioned your path with http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/CSS/quote.css it is just a example but please provide full path to get Template as you want.

link href="http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/CSS/quote.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"